# PHP Mysql, assign a default value if user submit empty

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to give a default value if the user submit an empty value like `[{"photourl":""}]` using php and mysql query. I'm not really familiar with backend so i'm not sure my code is correct or not.

```html
<?php
function profile_put($dt) 
{
 $query="update personal set fullname='".$dt[0]["name"]."', dob='".$dt[0]["dob"]."', 
 gender='".$dt[0]["gender"]."', country='".$dt[0]["country"]."', city='".$dt[0]["city"]."', photourl='".$dt[0]["photourl"]."',
 lastupdate='15 minutes', about='', website='' 
 where huffid='".$dt[0]["huffid"]."';";

 if($dt[0]["photourl"]=="")
  {
   $dt[0]["photourl"]='https://i.imgur.com/KbHbcqV.png';
  }

 return $query;
}
?>
```

Then i tried the API using postman, the body looks like this 
`[{
    "huffid":"newuser",
    "dob":"121212",
    "gender":"male",
    "country":"singapore",
    "city":"singapore",
    "photourl": ""
}]`
From the frontend, if the user doesn't give any photo the `photourl` will empty just like what i sent using postman. The `photourl` in database column also emoty. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the default value *before* you put it into `$query`. Statements execute in order, you can't refer to a value until after you assign it.

```
<?php
function profile_put($dt) 
{
    if($dt[0]["photourl"]=="")
    {
        $dt[0]["photourl"]='https://i.imgur.com/KbHbcqV.png';
    }

    $query="update personal set fullname='".$dt[0]["name"]."', dob='".$dt[0]["dob"]."', 
    gender='".$dt[0]["gender"]."', country='".$dt[0]["country"]."', city='".$dt[0]["city"]."', photourl='".$dt[0]["photourl"]."',
    lastupdate='15 minutes', about='', website='' 
    where huffid='".$dt[0]["huffid"]."';";

    return $query;
}
?>
```

You should also learn to use prepared queries rather than substituting strings into SQL.

Comment: For proper coding better you put if(empty(trim($dt[0]["photourl"]==""))) to replace if($dt[0]["photourl"]=="") because sometimes user keyin spacebar..